# Unique triplets from pairs

Tags: mysql

I have a table (mysql) in the following pairs' structure:

```
 home   | door
 table  | window
 door   | table
 window | home
 home   | table
 table  | door
```

I'm looking for the best solution (fast and logical, to run on large tables) to get all unique triplets i.e home is paired with door and also with window so that's a triplet, and it's cardinal order so window,door,home is not distinct from door,home,window etc.

Wanted results:

```
home  | door   | window 
home  | door   | table 
home  | window | table 
table | door   | window
```

Comment: What should the result be for the sample table/data?

Comment: home, door, window-
home, door, table-
home, window, table-
table, door, window-

Comment: Assuming the following tuples:  (table, window), (table, door), is (table, window, door) a triplet?

Comment: I edited the question. I assumed that your table structure is two columns. Please edit and provide table and column names.

Comment: @Lennart it seems that the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @Lenhart, yes it is

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand the problem properly but here is a sketch that might get you going:

```
create table t 
( a char(10) not null
, b char(10) not null
,     primary key(a,b));

insert into t (a,b) 
values ('home','door')
      ,('table','window')
      ,('door','table')
      ,('window','home')
      ,('home','table')
      ,('table','door');
```

For simplicity, we define a view so that a < b:

```
create view v as 
    select distinct least(a,b) as a, greatest(a,b) as b from t;
```

Now we know that we can chain v via a self-join. As ybercube pointed out:

```
select v1.a, v1.b, v2.b 
from v as v1 
join v as v2 
    on v1.b = v2.a;
```

won't work if we have the tuples (a,b),(a,c). So we add other connections as:

```
select distinct v1.a, v1.b, v2.b  
from v as v1  
join v as v2
  on v1.a in (v2.a, v2.b) or v1.b in (v2.a, v2.b)
where v1.a<v1.b 
  and v1.b<v2.b;
```

Needless to say, this will be very inefficient for large tables.

Comment: Using the view does not guerantee you'll get all the triplets. What if two rows (of the table or view) are `(a,b)` and `(a,c)`? `(a,b,c)` will not appear in the results.

Comment: You are correct, I started out using on a=a union a=b union b=a union b=b but figured I'd be smart. Note to self, stop trying to be smart when you're not;-)

Comment: Thanks. that's something I thought of too, yet as @ypercubeᵀᴹ mentioned if the connection is in the same row It won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following queries will help you ... (1) find all (single) elements and allocate ids, (2) find all possible combinations - in the mathematical sense (MySQL 5.7).

```
-- using your test data
-- (1)
create table first
as
select
  dt.c1 word
, @rownum := @rownum + 1 id
from
  ( select c1 from pairs union select c2 from pairs ) dt
, ( select @rownum := 0 ) row_
;

mysql> select * from first;
+--------+------+
| word   | id   |
+--------+------+
| home   |    1 |
| table  |    2 |
| door   |    3 |
| window |    4 |
+--------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Query: find all triplets

```
-- (2)
select
  t1.word
, t2.word
, t3.word
from first t1
  join first t2 on t1.id < t2.id
  join first t3 on t2.id < t3.id
order by t1.word, t2.word, t3.word  -- optional
;

-- result
+-------+-------+--------+
| word  | word  | word   |
+-------+-------+--------+
| home  | door  | window |
| home  | table | door   |
| home  | table | window |
| table | door  | window |
+-------+-------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Slightly bigger example:

```
-- test data
create table pairs2 as
select 'a' c1, 'b' c2 from dual union
select 'b', 'a' from dual union 
select 'a', 'c' from dual union 
select 'c', 'a' from dual union 
select 'b', 'c' from dual union 
select 'c', 'b' from dual union 
select 'x', 'y' from dual union 
select 'y', 'x' from dual union 
select 'x', 'z' from dual union 
select 'z', 'x' from dual union 
select 'y', 'z' from dual union 
select 'z', 'y' from dual ;
```

Create the first table (as before), then run the second query:

```
drop table first ;
-- same as before
create table first
as
select
  dt.c1 word
, @rownum := @rownum + 1 id
from
  ( select c1 from pairs2 union select c2 from pairs2 ) dt
, ( select @rownum := 0 ) row_
;
```

Query (2) and result

```
mysql> select
    ->   t1.word
    -> , t2.word
    -> , t3.word
    -> from first t1
    ->   join first t2 on t1.id < t2.id
    ->   join first t3 on t2.id < t3.id
    -> order by t1.word, t2.word, t3.word
    -> ;
+------+------+------+
| word | word | word |
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
| a    | b    | x    |
| a    | b    | y    |
| a    | b    | z    |
| a    | c    | x    |
| a    | c    | y    |
| a    | c    | z    |
| a    | x    | y    |
| a    | x    | z    |
| a    | y    | z    |
| b    | c    | x    |
| b    | c    | y    |
| b    | c    | z    |
| b    | x    | y    |
| b    | x    | z    |
| b    | y    | z    |
| c    | x    | y    |
| c    | x    | z    |
| c    | y    | z    |
| x    | y    | z    |
+------+------+------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Dbfiddle (MariaDB) [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=90debd582083b525d7176a652a75f377).

Comment: You don't need the id as an order attribute, the implicit lexical order will work fine.

Comment: *‘home is paired with door and also with window so that's a triplet’* – I understand that to mean that only items explicitly linked in the source table should form triplets. For the data sample your query is using, there would only be two valid triplets, `a,b,c` and `x,y,z`.

Comment: @AndriyM - Thanks for reading my answer!  My reason for posting it : Lennart's solution had not been "accepted", so I thought I should write something that casts the net a bit further.  This is also why I have included the second example, as the (second) result set shows the differences between the 2 approaches (Lennart's and mine) quite drastically.  I shall remove my posting if Lennart's answer is accepted.

Comment: @Lennart - Not quite sure what you mean by "order attribute" and "implicit lexical order", respectively.  AFAIK, when SELECTing, the order of a result set is not predetermined, unless an ORDER BY clause is used.  Also, I have not written "ordered by ID ..." anywhere.  Would it be possible for you to give me some more details?

Comment: In first you create an ordering number id which is used in your join later on: `t1.id < t2.id`. You might as well use `t1.word < t2.word`